# C2248 - From to 2 inheritances

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

I have 3 classes, 1 inherited by another. A->B->C. A has a protected member function that I'm trying to set using C.

I'm getting C2248 -
Error   C2248   'A::status': cannot access inaccessible member declared in class 'A'    Associations

Am I not allowed to access to the variable in class C?

```
 class A {
 public:
     A();
     ~A();
 protected:
     char status[4];
 };

 class B: class A {
 public:
     B();
     ~B();
 };

 class C: class B {
 public:
     C(char newStatus[4]);
 };
 C::C(char newStatus[4])
 {
     this.status = newStatus;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default inheritance strategy is private.  That means that `status` will turn into a private member in `B` and will be inaccessible in `C`, see [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339)
 for more info. 
 Hence you want to inherit publicly.  Also arrays do not support assignment, use `std::array` instead.

```
#include <array>

class A {
public:
    A();
    ~A();

protected:
    std::array<char,4> status;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    ~B();
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C(std::array<char,4> const &newStatus);
};
C::C(std::array<char,4> const &newStatus) {
    this->status = newStatus;
}
```